# Does a Java Lock object enforce a happens-before relationship?

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, memory-model, happens-before

Java provides a Lock object in the concurrency package that according to the documentation `provides more extensive locking operations than can be obtained using synchronized methods and statements.`

The synchronized methods/blocks besides mutual exclusion, enforce a happens-before relationship which makes sure that changed made to the variable by one thread are visible to the other.

Does this relationship occur when using a Lock object? Is observation guaranteed like in the case of synchronized block for all platforms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this relationship occur when using a Lock object? Is observation
>   guaranteed like in the case of synchronized block for all platforms?

Yes, it does.

There are several actions that create happens-before relationships and one of them is synchronization ([here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/memconsist.html)), and Java's lock object is also meant for that purpose.

Read about Java's [Memory Consistency Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility) from Oracle docs. Except below which will be highlight in the link.

In below "*extend these guarantees*" means memory consistency properties like "happens-before" relationships. `Lock` class belongs to subpackage of `java.util.concurrent`, so it guarantees memory consistency properties like "happens-before" relationships and more.

> The methods of all classes in java.util.concurrent and its subpackages
>   extend these guarantees to higher-level synchronization.

Comment: Also the Memory Constistency Properties doc states explicetley:
"Actions prior to "releasing" synchronizer methods such as Lock.unlock, Semaphore.release, and CountDownLatch.countDown happen-before actions subsequent to a successful "acquiring" method such as Lock.lock, Semaphore.acquire, Condition.await, and CountDownLatch.await on the same synchronizer object in another thread."

Comment: Yes, it is one of the best pages to read about why, how and what lies inside `java.util.concurrent` package.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it does.

> Lock objects work very much like the implicit locks used by
>   synchronized code. **As with implicit locks, only one thread can own a
>   Lock object at a time**. Lock objects also support a wait/notify
>   mechanism, through their associated Condition objects.

From https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html

Comment: Everything you say here is true, but you did not answer the question.

Comment: @jameslarge: Does a Java Lock object enforce a happens-before relationship?Yes, it does.As with implicit locks, only one thread can own a Lock object at a time   -- Isn't that an answer?

Comment: Yes, but you answer only talks about mutual exclusion and condition variables.  It doesn't say "happens-before" anywhere.  The idea of a "happens-before" guarantee is a completely separate topic from how many threads can own a mutex at a given time.

Comment: @jameslarge: Sorry you don't get it, but the idea of a "happens-before" guarantee is directly relationated with the fact that only one thread can own a Lock object at a time.

Comment: How so?  Mutexes have been in Java since the very beginning, but the first mention of a "happens before"-like relationship in Java mutexes was https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=133 -- first implemented in the Java 5 platform.  I am not aware of any theory that says you can't implement a mutex without also providing memory consistency between threads.  (I _am_ aware of books that explain why you _shouldn't_ do it.  http://www.amazon.com/Art-Multiprocessor-Programming-Revised-Reprint/dp/0123973376/ )

Comment: @jameslarge: Checked your link and it doesn´t include the phrase "happens-before" anywhere (just like my not-answer!). BTW, Lock interface was included in Java 5, as you've probably read on *many* books.